# How to get the relationships in a couple of paths?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm the new to neo4j(stackoverflow too),I have a question that I googled a long time but I can't find answer.
I want to get the relationships in a couple of paths,I use this cql find 3 paths

```
match p=(a)-[*]->(b) where id(a)=20 AND id(b)=25 return relationships(p)
```

Here's the result
[paths result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndwVb.png)

As you can see,there are few relationship are repetitive.
How can I get the relationship(or count) that not repetitive in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED]

This should work:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*]->(b)
WHERE ID(a) = 20 AND ID(b) = 25
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(p) AS rel
RETURN DISTINCT rel;
```